# macOS Big Sur : Python quit unexpectedly error

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, macos-big-sur

I have recently migrated my Django project and started setting up everything on my new mac. Now, whenever I'm executing `python manage.py runserver` command to run the `Django server`, it throws `**python quit unexpectedly**`.

I'm using `python3` and `pip3` to install the package in my `virtualenv`. I have tried everything, but I'm unable to resolve this error. I don't know what I have  messed up here, but seriously it is becoming pain and I'm falling back. Any kind of help would be much appreciated.

Error details:

```
Process:               Python [7573]
Path:                  /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:            Python
Version:               3.9.5 (3.9.5)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        Python [7572]
Responsible:           Terminal [783]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2021-07-03 20:05:57.350 +0530
OS Version:            macOS 11.4 (20F71)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     3.0 (14Y908)
Anonymous UUID:        68A5DC7A-5C23-74BF-2442-42CA9CC622A0

Sleep/Wake UUID:       2F9DD3EA-B706-4C61-86A3-AD04DB1842CE

Time Awake Since Boot: 5500 seconds
Time Since Wake:       4700 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        1

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
Assertion failed: (filename && *filename), function try_dlopen, file libltdl/ltdl.c, line 1204.
 

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff204d3e8a readlink + 10
1   org.python.python               0x000000010bb42a05 os_readlink_impl + 116
2   org.python.python               0x000000010bb36116 os_readlink + 229
3   org.python.python               0x000000010ba0e98f cfunction_vectorcall_FASTCALL_KEYWORDS + 90
4   org.python.python               0x000000010babbc53 call_function + 164
5   org.python.python               0x000000010bab9526 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 45324
6   org.python.python               0x000000010b9c4240 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 192
7   org.python.python               0x000000010babbc53 call_function + 164
8   org.python.python               0x000000010bab9489 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 45167
9   org.python.python               0x000000010baad2d6 _PyEval_EvalCode + 403
10  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c42f8 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 376
11  org.python.python               0x000000010babbc53 call_function + 164
12  org.python.python               0x000000010bab9562 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 45384
13  org.python.python               0x000000010baad2d6 _PyEval_EvalCode + 403
14  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c42f8 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 376
15  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c6e7a method_vectorcall + 160
16  org.python.python               0x000000010babbc53 call_function + 164
17  org.python.python               0x000000010bab9612 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 45560
18  org.python.python               0x000000010baad2d6 _PyEval_EvalCode + 403
19  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c42f8 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 376
20  org.python.python               0x000000010babbc53 call_function + 164
21  org.python.python               0x000000010bab9489 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 45167
22  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c4240 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 192
23  org.python.python               0x000000010bb5e1f1 bounded_lru_cache_wrapper + 312
24  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c36da _PyObject_MakeTpCall + 129
25  org.python.python               0x000000010babbcbd call_function + 270
26  org.python.python               0x000000010bab9562 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 45384
27  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c4240 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 192
28  org.python.python               0x000000010babbc53 call_function + 164
29  org.python.python               0x000000010bab9562 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 45384
30  org.python.python               0x000000010b9d7189 gen_send_ex + 177
31  org.python.python               0x000000010bab8458 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 41022
32  org.python.python               0x000000010b9d7189 gen_send_ex + 177
33  org.python.python               0x000000010bab8458 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 41022
34  org.python.python               0x000000010b9d7189 gen_send_ex + 177
35  org.python.python               0x000000010baa8bf3 builtin_next + 71
36  org.python.python               0x000000010ba0ea43 cfunction_vectorcall_FASTCALL + 95
37  org.python.python               0x000000010babbc53 call_function + 164
38  org.python.python               0x000000010bab9562 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 45384
39  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c4240 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 192
40  org.python.python               0x000000010babbc53 call_function + 164
41  org.python.python               0x000000010bab9489 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 45167
42  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c4240 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 192
43  org.python.python               0x000000010babbc53 call_function + 164
44  org.python.python               0x000000010bab9489 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 45167
45  org.python.python               0x000000010baad2d6 _PyEval_EvalCode + 403
46  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c42f8 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 376
47  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c3ee1 PyVectorcall_Call + 164
48  org.python.python               0x000000010bab975e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 45892
49  org.python.python               0x000000010baad2d6 _PyEval_EvalCode + 403
50  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c42f8 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 376
51  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c3ee1 PyVectorcall_Call + 164
52  org.python.python               0x000000010bab975e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 45892
53  org.python.python               0x000000010baad2d6 _PyEval_EvalCode + 403
54  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c42f8 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 376
55  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c6e7a method_vectorcall + 160
56  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c3ee1 PyVectorcall_Call + 164
57  org.python.python               0x000000010bab975e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 45892
58  org.python.python               0x000000010baad2d6 _PyEval_EvalCode + 403
59  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c42f8 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 376
60  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c6e7a method_vectorcall + 160
61  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c3ee1 PyVectorcall_Call + 164
62  org.python.python               0x000000010bab975e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 45892
63  org.python.python               0x000000010baad2d6 _PyEval_EvalCode + 403
64  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c42f8 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 376
65  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c6e7a method_vectorcall + 160
66  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c3ee1 PyVectorcall_Call + 164
67  org.python.python               0x000000010bab975e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 45892
68  org.python.python               0x000000010baad2d6 _PyEval_EvalCode + 403
69  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c42f8 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 376
70  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c6e7a method_vectorcall + 160
71  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c3ee1 PyVectorcall_Call + 164
72  org.python.python               0x000000010bab975e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 45892
73  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c4240 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 192
74  org.python.python               0x000000010babbc53 call_function + 164
75  org.python.python               0x000000010bab9489 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 45167
76  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c4240 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 192
77  org.python.python               0x000000010babbc53 call_function + 164
78  org.python.python               0x000000010bab9489 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 45167
79  org.python.python               0x000000010baad2d6 _PyEval_EvalCode + 403
80  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c42f8 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 376
81  org.python.python               0x000000010babbc53 call_function + 164
82  org.python.python               0x000000010bab9562 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 45384
83  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c4240 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 192
84  org.python.python               0x000000010babbc53 call_function + 164
85  org.python.python               0x000000010bab9562 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 45384
86  org.python.python               0x000000010baad2d6 _PyEval_EvalCode + 403
87  org.python.python               0x000000010bb10567 run_eval_code_obj + 126
88  org.python.python               0x000000010bb104b7 run_mod + 96
89  org.python.python               0x000000010bb0ddac pyrun_file + 173
90  org.python.python               0x000000010bb0d7ad pyrun_simple_file + 272
91  org.python.python               0x000000010bb0d677 PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 67
92  org.python.python               0x000000010bb2c365 pymain_run_file + 327
93  org.python.python               0x000000010bb2bab5 pymain_run_python + 460
94  org.python.python               0x000000010bb2b8ad Py_RunMain + 23
95  org.python.python               0x000000010bb2cbca pymain_main + 35
96  org.python.python               0x000000010bb2cea0 Py_BytesMain + 42
97  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff20522f5d start + 1

Thread 1 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff204d892e __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff205075bd pthread_kill + 263
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff2045c411 abort + 120
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff2045b7e8 __assert_rtn + 314
4   libltdl.7.dylib                 0x000000010daa5cb3 try_dlopen.cold.2 + 35
5   libltdl.7.dylib                 0x000000010daa4060 try_dlopen + 3115
6   libltdl.7.dylib                 0x000000010daa3210 lt_dlopen + 42
7   libodbc.2.dylib                 0x000000010da453c2 __connect_part_one + 674
8   libodbc.2.dylib                 0x000000010da640c2 SQLDriverConnectW + 1330
9   pyodbc.cpython-39-darwin.so     0x000000010da14601 Connection_New(_object*, bool, bool, long, bool, _object*, Object&) + 689
10  pyodbc.cpython-39-darwin.so     0x000000010da2085c mod_connect(_object*, _object*, _object*) + 1644
11  org.python.python               0x000000010ba0e09c cfunction_call + 52
12  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c36da _PyObject_MakeTpCall + 129
13  org.python.python               0x000000010babbcbd call_function + 270
14  org.python.python               0x000000010bab9612 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 45560
15  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c4240 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 192
16  org.python.python               0x000000010babbc53 call_function + 164
17  org.python.python               0x000000010bab9489 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 45167
18  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c4240 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 192
19  org.python.python               0x000000010babbc53 call_function + 164
20  org.python.python               0x000000010bab9489 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 45167
21  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c4240 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 192
22  org.python.python               0x000000010babbc53 call_function + 164
23  org.python.python               0x000000010bab9489 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 45167
24  org.python.python               0x000000010baad2d6 _PyEval_EvalCode + 403
25  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c42f8 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 376
26  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c6e7a method_vectorcall + 160
27  org.python.python               0x000000010babbc53 call_function + 164
28  org.python.python               0x000000010bab9526 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 45324
29  org.python.python               0x000000010baad2d6 _PyEval_EvalCode + 403
30  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c42f8 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 376
31  org.python.python               0x000000010babbc53 call_function + 164
32  org.python.python               0x000000010bab9489 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 45167
33  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c4240 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 192
34  org.python.python               0x000000010babbc53 call_function + 164
35  org.python.python               0x000000010bab9489 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 45167
36  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c4240 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 192
37  org.python.python               0x000000010babbc53 call_function + 164
38  org.python.python               0x000000010bab9489 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 45167
39  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c4240 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 192
40  org.python.python               0x000000010babbc53 call_function + 164
41  org.python.python               0x000000010bab9489 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 45167
42  org.python.python               0x000000010baad2d6 _PyEval_EvalCode + 403
43  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c42f8 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 376
44  org.python.python               0x000000010babbc53 call_function + 164
45  org.python.python               0x000000010bab9489 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 45167
46  org.python.python               0x000000010baad2d6 _PyEval_EvalCode + 403
47  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c42f8 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 376
48  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c3907 _PyObject_FastCallDictTstate + 87
49  org.python.python               0x000000010ba32aea slot_tp_init + 192
50  org.python.python               0x000000010ba3c2cc type_call + 272
51  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c36da _PyObject_MakeTpCall + 129
52  org.python.python               0x000000010babbcbd call_function + 270
53  org.python.python               0x000000010bab9562 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 45384
54  org.python.python               0x000000010baad2d6 _PyEval_EvalCode + 403
55  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c42f8 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 376
56  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c3907 _PyObject_FastCallDictTstate + 87
57  org.python.python               0x000000010ba32aea slot_tp_init + 192
58  org.python.python               0x000000010ba3c2cc type_call + 272
59  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c36da _PyObject_MakeTpCall + 129
60  org.python.python               0x000000010babbcbd call_function + 270
61  org.python.python               0x000000010bab9562 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 45384
62  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c4240 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 192
63  org.python.python               0x000000010babbc53 call_function + 164
64  org.python.python               0x000000010bab9489 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 45167
65  org.python.python               0x000000010baad2d6 _PyEval_EvalCode + 403
66  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c42f8 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 376
67  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c6e7a method_vectorcall + 160
68  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c3ee1 PyVectorcall_Call + 164
69  org.python.python               0x000000010bab975e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 45892
70  org.python.python               0x000000010baad2d6 _PyEval_EvalCode + 403
71  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c42f8 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 376
72  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c3ee1 PyVectorcall_Call + 164
73  org.python.python               0x000000010bab975e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 45892
74  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c4240 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 192
75  org.python.python               0x000000010babbc53 call_function + 164
76  org.python.python               0x000000010bab9489 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 45167
77  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c4240 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 192
78  org.python.python               0x000000010babbc53 call_function + 164
79  org.python.python               0x000000010bab9489 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 45167
80  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c4240 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 192
81  org.python.python               0x000000010b9c6fbb method_vectorcall + 481
82  org.python.python               0x000000010bb78ff9 t_bootstrap + 122
83  org.python.python               0x000000010bb1db50 pythread_wrapper + 36
84  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff205078fc _pthread_start + 224
85  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20503443 thread_start + 15

Thread 1 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000700003505000  rcx: 0x00007000034feb68  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000d03  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x00007000034feb90  rsp: 0x00007000034feb68
   r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x0000700003505000  r11: 0x0000000000000246
  r12: 0x0000000000000d03  r13: 0x0000000110038000  r14: 0x0000000000000006  r15: 0x0000000000000016
  rip: 0x00007fff204d892e  rfl: 0x0000000000000246  cr2: 0x0000000110038000
  
Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x02000148
Trap Number:     133

Thread 1 instruction stream not available.

Thread 1 last branch register state not available.

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=600.5M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=600.5M(100%)
Writable regions: Total=166.9M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=166.9M(100%)
 
                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
Kernel Alloc Once                    8K        1 
MALLOC                            85.2M       54 
MALLOC guard page                   16K        4 
MALLOC_LARGE (reserved)            128K        1         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
STACK GUARD                          8K        2 
Stack                             32.0M        2 
VM_ALLOCATE                       48.8M      198 
__DATA                            4118K      205 
__DATA_CONST                      7228K      136 
__DATA_DIRTY                       288K       62 
__LINKEDIT                       503.2M      110 
__OBJC_RO                         70.2M        1 
__OBJC_RW                         2480K        2 
__TEXT                            97.7M      204 
__UNICODE                          588K        1 
shared memory                        8K        2 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                            851.7M      985 
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space   851.6M      985 

Model: MacBookPro14,3, BootROM 429.120.4.0.0, 4 processors, Quad-Core Intel Core i7, 2.9 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.45f5
Graphics: kHW_IntelHDGraphics630Item, Intel HD Graphics 630, spdisplays_builtin
Graphics: kHW_AMDRadeonPro560Item, Radeon Pro 560, spdisplays_pcie_device, 4 GB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, LPDDR3, 2133 MHz, 0x802C, 0x4D5435324C31473332443450472D30393320
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, LPDDR3, 2133 MHz, 0x802C, 0x4D5435324C31473332443450472D30393320
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x173), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.77.111.1 AirPortDriverBrcmNIC-1680.8)
Bluetooth: Version 8.0.5d7, 3 services, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: Apple T1 Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 41.4
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 41.4
```